# Using bootstrap twitter with google blogger

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, blogger

I've been trying to use bootstrap twitter on my google blog on blogger.com. Apparently it is not working, and I am quite sure that the problem is how I am including the css and js files. I've uploaded the .css and .js files as .txt files to an online plain .txt upload server. I am including them in the head.

bootstrap.css

```
<link href='http://m.uploadedit.com/b013/1366225851722.txt' rel='stylesheet'/>
```

bootstrap.min.css

```
<link href='http://m.uploadedit.com/b013/1366225875450.txt' rel='stylesheet'/>
```

bootstrap-responsive.css

```
<link href='http://m.uploadedit.com/b013/136622647822.txt' rel='stylesheet'/>
```

JQUERY

```
<script src='//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js'/>
<script src='//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.min.js'/>  
<script src='http://m.uploadedit.com/b013/1366226081928.txt'/>
```

bootstrap.js

```
<script src='http://m.uploadedit.com/b013/1366225665368.txt'/>
```

bootsrap.min.js

```
<script src='http://m.uploadedit.com/b013/1366225732588.txt'/>
```

Is it not possible to link to these files when they are .txt? If not what alternatives do I have? I've seen both dropbox and google drive mentioned on a blog post, but as far as I've tried and searched for It is not possible to have a plain text page - dropbox and drive adds html for their interfaces.

**UPDATE:** 
I solved it by using a free webhost uploading the plain .js and .css like [THIS](http://bootstrapfiles.webege.com/) - I just googled "free webhost".

The problem is that free webhosts can be rather slow - and the webhost I've chosen informs about DDOS attacks. Is there a better alternative - if I do not want to pay for serverspace?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use netdna's cdn for bootstrap: http://www.bootstrapcdn.com

I'm using it and I'm highly satisfied with the result (http://pr-nizar.blogspot.com).

Or you can use DropBox as a CDN if you're using a customized version of bootstrap.

Answer (score 2):

What about if you use links of Bootstrap Twitter files from [jsDeliver](http://www.jsdelivr.com/#!bootstrap) which is a free CDN for javascript libraries, jQuery plugins, fonts and CSS frameworks.