# building blogger template with bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, blogger

I've just learned bootstrap and I'm excited to integrate bootstrap in my blogger. I'm using the free version of blogger, not using any custom domain. Then I realize that blogger is using xml with lots of  tags, I'm confused to integrate the html I made with bootstrap, to that blogger version.

I've googled and read the article [Using bootstrap twitter with google blogger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16070994/using-bootstrap-twitter-with-google-blogger), but it doesn't explain anything about the tags in blogger's xml body. Other google results are also not answering my confusion. How to build a blogger template and integrate it with bootstrap? Is it possible to have a sleek look of bootstrap without custom domain in blogger? Your answers, any tutorial link, tutorial video, and samples are highly appreciated :)

Comment: Please be more specific about the question , where you are getting issue or where you are not.

Answer (score 0):

Better late than never, Yes, you can use bootstrap without custom domain in blogger. I'm using it in [my blog](http://teqnyaa.blogspot.com/) and in building blogger templates. All you need to do is to use Bootstrap CDN links in the head then you can use bootstrap components and classes in the body and with divs. this is an example for [using bootstrap with blogger templates.](http://www.bloggertipspro.com/2016/01/using-bootstrap-with-blogger-templates.html)

**Note** : With XML you must close all HTML elements properly like this `<meta charset="utf-8"/>`

Comment: going to try this soon after finishing my current project! thank you :D

Answer (score -1):

My friend has a [GitHub repository](https://github.com/bootsblogger) dedicated to convert **Bootstrap** framework to **Blogger** template.

**Demo:** https://bootsblogger.github.io